# Specific iBeacon Detection in Background

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I've been searching around to find a straight answer to a problem I'm facing and the information is a little scattered. I'm not sure whether it's possible or not based on the answers.

Basically I'm using `iBeacons` as a component to my app. The scenario is this, you have a high street with numerous shops. Each shop has 1 beacon in their window facing to the street. A generic shopping app is on the user's phone.

When a user walks up the high street I want a user to receive a notification when passing a shop. This notification would say something like "Check out `MyShops` latest offers and discounts" with a prompt to open the app. This is all as the app is in the background.

All the beacons have a *consistent UDID which tie to my app*. And each shop would have it's own major identifier.

I want the notification to be specific to a shop (with a specific beacon major and minor) but I cannot find a way of determining which beacon was entered while in the background.

Also some shops may be close and have broadcast overlap, will the background process for entering a region trigger for each beacon you get in range of if they have the same *UDID*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want with a common app that launches the other store-specific apps once it is brought to the foreground by a user tapping the local notification.

A few points:

1. You must combine `CoreLocation` monitoring and ranging APIs to do this.  Monitoring will wake up the app into the background on beacon detection (but only for 10 secs) and ranging will give you updates every second with an `NSArray` containing all visible beacons with the full beacon identifiers and a distance estimate for each.
2. In the ranging callback, you can compare the estimated distance to all visible beacons to determine which is closest (`CLBeacon.accuracy`).  The closest one is what should send the local notification for the shop.
3. Do not confuse the beacon `ProximityUUID` with the iOS device's unique UDID.  The two have nothing to do with one another.

Comment: Is the ranging triggered only when entering a beacon range? I envisage some shops having overlap on their beacon so I'd want to trigger the beacon when close to the shop door. But the beacon's range from two shops causes an overlap meaning 'Shop A' would trigger the notification but at the same time you've already entered the range of 'Shop B'. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense, and overlaps of beacons in the same region are indeed a problem.  If you are in a situation where you can control the beacon identifiers, you can solve this by having 20 different regions (the max allowed by iOS for each app) with each region having a different UUID or UUID/major combo.  Then make sure all nearby shows use beacons for different regions.  This way, you get enter/exit events as you pass by the shops and you get a new chance to range in the background.  Not perfect, but it helps.